# Api gateway 304 responses with Last-Modified header

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I want to response a 304 response with Last-Modified header.

At first I use Error response to implement.

Handler.js

```
module.exports.handler = function(event, context, cb) {
  const UpdateDate = new Date();
  return cb("304 Not Modified", {
    "Last-Modified": UpdateDate,
    "body":{
      "message": {}
    }
  });
};
```

s-function.json in endpoints

```
"responses": {
    "304 Not Modified.*": {
      "statusCode": "304",
      "responseParameters": {
        "method.response.header.Last-Modified": "integration.response.body.Last-Modified"
      },
      "responseModels": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "Empty"
      },
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "$input.json('$.body')"
      }
    },
    "default": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "responseParameters": {
        "method.response.header.Cache-Control": "'public, max-age=86400'",
        "method.response.header.Last-Modified": "integration.response.body.Last-Modified"
      },
      "responseModels": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "Empty"
      },
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "$input.json('$.body')"

      }
    }
}
```

However, I find it on Lambda doc.

> If an error is provided, callback parameter is ignored.

So, this doesn't work.

Is there any solution to response a 304 response with header?

Updated:

Is it possible to return a Error object and map responses 304 in s-function? Below code can't map to 304.

s-funtion.json

```
"responses": {
    ".*304 Not Modified.*": {
      "statusCode": "304",
      "responseParameters": {
        "method.response.header.Cache-Control": "'public, max-age=86400'",
        "method.response.header.Last-Modified": "integration.response.body.errorMessage.Last-Modified"
      }
}
```

Handler.js

```
return cb({
  "status" : "304 Not Modified",
  "Last-Modified": UpdateDate
), null);
```

I also try this. It can mapping to 304 but header can't get "integration.response.body.errorMessage.Last-Modified"

```
return cb(JSON.stringify({
  "status" : "304 Not Modified",
  "Last-Modified": UpdateDate
}), null);
```

I try $util.parseJson but not working on responseParameter.

> Invalid mapping expression specified:$util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage')).Last-Modified

```
 "responseParameters": {
        "method.response.header.Cache-Control": "'public, max-age=86400'",
        "method.response.header.Last-Modified": "$util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage')).Last-Modified"
  },
```

Comment: Please look at Ryan's link in Option 2. Your update does not actually return an error.

Comment: @BobKinney It's return an error. In cloudWatch Logs: 
{
    "errorMessage": "{\"status\":\"304 Not Modified\",\"Last-Modified\":\"2016-07-22T01:58:10.857Z\"}"
}

Comment: Side note, 304's should not return response bodies according to W3. Just referring to your 1st example.

Comment: Thanks, finally I only put 304 status code in response and null body to implement cache control. And setting Last-Modified header in 200 response .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return status 304 in your API, you would need to throw an error from your Lambda function. It is possible to return the "Last-Modified" value in the error message from your Lambda function and route that to the "Last-Modified" header in the API response.

For details have a look at Option 2 [here](https://rpgreen.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/how-to-http-redirects-with-api-gateway-and-lambda/)

Thanks,
Ryan